# When i select CheckBox().I need to update its value into DB - MVC2,AJAx,JQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery

Please find the code which i tried to update the DB using MVC2.But unable to update

View Page with Ajax Code

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   $('#cbID').click(function(){
    $.ajax({ url: 'Home/About',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { checkbox: $('#cbID').attr('checked') },
    success: function(o) { alert('saved'); }
                      });
</script>
<div class="bgDiv">
<input id="cbID" type="checkbox" name="SelectedObject" value="cbValue" />
```

Controller page code

```
 public ActionResult About(string str)
        {
            AboutModels ObjAM = new AboutModels();//model class name
            polloptions = ObjAM.dbValue(str);//call the model function to udate the table
            return View();
        }
```

Please advice

Answer (score 1):

you should either declare your event handler in ready function or declare it with live or delegate methods like

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function(){   
  $('#cbID').click(function(){
    $.ajax({ url: 'Home/About',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { checkbox: $('#cbID').attr('checked') },
    success: function(o) { alert('saved'); }
                      });
      });
 });
</script>
```

the problem is that your script is running before the required checkbox is rendered so putting it in ready will wait until document is ready or live will bind it on document level where the event will reach through propogation

Comment: Sorry i am not cleared can you please elaborate your explanation

Comment: Please try the code first and also tell me what specific point you want me to explain

Comment: I have updated my <script> and run it. But i didn get the output what i expect.

Comment: If my understanding correct - alert box will come after i select the check box rite?

Comment: we had mismatching braces and parenthesis in code. corrected the code. plz give it a try and do consider using http://getfirebug.com/ for js debugging

Comment: Thkx Muhammad.. its working.. but this code is not working in firefox sometime.. Please advice

Comment: can you explain what is not working. have you debugged if request is getting through to the server side

Comment: Actually i am using Fiefox browser.As per my code after i clicked the check box i will get the alert popup wit saved.I got the popup only once.. but after sometime i didn get any popup..Sorry unable to download so yet to debug my code.. Please advice

Comment: Sorry, No luck... I have added a my view page here.. please check that too..and help me please..

Comment: Do i need to set anything in my firefox browser! Please advice